# Best way to store a time of a week

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a situation where I want users to be able to specify a time range, where the time is a relative range that exist in a given week. So a user could pick Monday 5PM - Tuesday 1AM. Think of it kind of like "what time is a person's work shift".

My first reaction is that I could store "relative" times. So assuming the week starts on Monday at 00:00:00, Monday at noon would be indicated as 86400/2=**43200**. I don't really like this method, because it makes handling time-zones a bit difficult.

Is there a "best" way for doing this (or just a good one)? Does MySQL have some sort of data type that deals with this specifically?

I've tagged this "Perl" and "MySQL", since I will be using them for this application, but the answer doesn't have to be specific to either of them technically.

Comment: Why not convert `Monday 5PM - Tuesday 1AM` to a `UTC datetime range` when query?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't the "converted" UTC datetime range be an absolute date? I am looking to store a way of representing "Every Tuesday from 1PM - 8PM", not "This specific Tuesday from 1PM - 8PM".

Comment: you ask which format is best, but you didn't specify how it would be used, so that you did not provide any information by which we can judge what is best. What kind of queries will be examining this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer will depend somewhat on what you will do with the data downstream.

But I would recommend avoiding any hacks and doing a straightforward approach (table syntax Sybase, since my MySQL is rusty - sorry)

```
CREATE TABLE weekday_ranges (
    start_dow    int,  -- 0-6 or 1-7 depending on what's easier downstream 
    start_hour   int,  -- 0-23
    start_minute int,  -- 0-59
    -- Add seconds/micorseconds as needed
    end_dow      int,
    end_hour     int,
    end_minute   int
)
```

An alternate approach is to store the offset ( in seconds ) from Sunday 00:00, both start and end offset. This offers its benefits (e.g. range comparisons are merely `<` and `>` operators instead of complex expressions).

Comment: I think I'd prefer the alternate approach, which is what I hinted at in my question. I think your solution works great on an application level, but it is hindered as a query.

Comment: @GoldenNewby - It works as a query, but is definitely uglier query-prettiness-wise compared to seconds offset approach. Where it wins is not needing to compute "Sunday 00:00" epoch # for every week on both storing AND retrieving

Answer (score -1):

Storing the start and end times in one field each (as opposed to broken down into parts) will allow the field to be indexed. Otherwise, there's not much difference. (It comes down to choosing whether the parts are assembled into one value in Perl or in SQL.)

There is indeed an unsolvable time zone issue: You have no way of differentiating the first 2am from the second 2am during the switch out of DST. There is simply not enough information in the input to handle that.

Comment: Well my thought on the timezone issue issue would be that 2AM always refers to the second 2AM. I can determine if a timezone happens in a given week by seeing the duration of the week in seconds as well.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, That doesn't solve anything. You still don't haev a means of refering to the first 2am. Now, it could be you never have to, but you have yet to say as much.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, Whether a timezone change happens in a given week has nothing to do with your question, so I don't know why you bring it up. If you bring that into play, you're complicating the issue for nothing.

Comment: My apologies. I had written timezone instead of daylight savings time.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, Same thing. That doesn't affect my comments.

Comment: For my purposes it doesn't need to be able to refer to the first 2am in a daylight savings situation. So as I said in my first comment, 2AM always refers to the second 2AM.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, then there's no time zone issue. 43200 can always refer to Monday at noon, etc.